# Android .aar dependencies aren’t resolving in libraries

Tags: java, android, android-studio, gradle, dependencies

My goal is to distribute an .aar file that can be used by other developers in their projects. The problem I find is when i try integrate my .aar into other project, is i need specify all of the dependencies in their build.gradle file that I have already included in my .aar build.gradle.

My question it if possible only include my library as a dependency and somehow the libraries that my library depends on will get included in the other project.

For example, my library defines the following dependencies in its build.gradle file:

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'org.altbeacon:android-beacon-library:2.3.5'
    compile 'commons-codec:commons-codec:1.10'
}
```

I wrote a test app that uses my library and add like module in Android Studio interface

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.5.0'
    compile project(':myLibrary')
}
```

However, this does not work. I get java.lang.VerifyErrors at runtime. What ends up working is to include this in the app's build.gradle file:

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.5.0'


    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'org.altbeacon:android-beacon-library:2.3.5'
    compile 'commons-codec:commons-codec:1.10'


    compile project(':myLibrary')
}
```

Why do I need to include dependencies in both the .aar and the final application? What am I not understanding about how dependencies work? Why isn't the final application able to grab the .aar's dependencies from maven or jCenter at build time?

Comment: If you're using an AAR in your test app, you wouldn't be adding a module in Android Studio, just a dependency line that points to a repository hosting your AAR file (be it a local repository or something like `mavenCentral` or `jcenter`).

Comment: I follow the following steps to add an external module

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=G27zMPLZm6o

Comment: How did you solve this?

Comment: no, the only way is add your transitive dependencies in your main project :(